# Ошибка при запуске дебаггинга VisualStudio: Вызванный объект был отключен от клиентов

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Не могу понять в чем дело, вне зависимости от проекта через некоторое время после простоя IDE(VisualStudio 2017), при попытке запустить отладку она выдает следующее
"вызванный объект был отключен от клиентов"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогает только перезагрузка Visual Studio.
Запускаю вроде с правами админа, что может быть?

Comment: Уже не помню какие ошибки были у меня, но первые версии как VS2017 так и windows 10 x64, вели себя похожим образом, после простоя студия ругалась окошками с ошибками. Методом тыка выявлено что такое происходило только после пробуждения из сна. Что помогло - понятия не имею. Толи обновления винды, толи обновления студии.

Comment: @Tomas нет винда не засыпает, причем это происходит даже при правке кода, допустим запустили дебаг все ок, пописали код минут 10 и потом вот  такая ошибка...

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу. Студия свежая. Ошибка: "Вызванный объект был отключен от клиентов" или иногда "OLE отправило запрос и ждет ответа".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновил Visual Studio и все стало ок